# In how many ways can 6 balls be selected so that there are at least 2 balls of each color? Why is this answer wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Index of this post: Question > my solution > Book's/Internet's solution > A request for help

Question: "A box contains 5 different red balls and 6 different white balls. In how many ways can 6 balls be selected so that there are at least 2 balls of each color?"

my solution:

Let's satisfy the main condition first: select $2$ red balls and $2$ white balls ($4$ in total), which is $5C2 \cdot 6C2 = 150$ ways.

Step 2: Select the remaining $2$ balls (we have already selected $4$ balls) from the remaining total ($7$ balls $= 5 - 2 + 6 - 2$). The number of ways is $7C2 = 21$.

Total number of ways: $150 \cdot 21 = 3150$.

Book's (matches with Googled solution):

Selection of $6$ balls consisting of at least $2$ balls of each colour from $5$ red and $6$ white balls, can be made as:

1. Select $2$ red balls and $4$ white balls
2. select $3$ red balls and $3$ white balls
3. select $4$ red balls and $2$ white balls

Total = $5C2 \cdot 6C4 + 5C3 \cdot 6C3 + 5C4 \cdot 6C2 = 10 \cdot 15 + 10 \cdot 20 + 5 \cdot 15 = 425$.

Request: I have no problem with the book's solution, but I can't figure out my mistake. Please explain what mistake I am making.

Comment: Replace the numbers 5, 6, 6, 2 with 2, 2, 3, 1 and write out the choices explicitly.  Compare what actually happens with what your formula predicts.

Comment: Also ChatGPT does not understand or incorporate the concept of logical validity -- don't ask it factual questions if what you want are reasoned answers.

Comment: @jbl , sir you said : """Replace the numbers  5, 6, 6, 2 with 2, 2, 3, 1 and write out the choices explicitly""" . i dont understand what you just said ( i am sorry. but i am a "not very smart" k11 student )

Comment: I am suggesting that you solve a simpler version of your question, where you will be able to write everything out explicitly.

Comment: "A box contains 5 different ..." Different how? Are all 11 balls unique? eg. pink, scarlet, cerise, maroon may all be called red. You may have answered a different question to the one you got an answer for.

Comment: @peterphipps i copied the exact question from the book , i think we can assume they are numbered . if this helps :  the solution in book starts like this : """ the selection of 6 balls , consisting of at least 2 balls of each colour from 5 red and 6 white balls can be made in the following ways : 1.  by selecting 2 red balls out of 5 balls and 4 white balls out of 6 , this can be done in ......................................"

Comment: You are overcounting. E.g.: you could have chosen red 1 and red 2 (imagine the balls are numbered) in step 1, then red 3 and red 4 in step 2. But you also count red 3, red 4 in step 1 and red 1, red 2 in step 2.

Comment: @PeterPhipps That has nothing to do with the issue here.  If you like, the balls are numbered so you can tell them apart, but some have the same color.  Siddh2e3's understanding of that part is fine.

Comment: actually i have made a mistake while reading book;s solution , pls wait 5.... mins to let me update it ...... edit : turns out .. no i haven't , sorry for disturbance

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4):

You count the following (among many other possibilities) more than once: "select the red balls called Alfie and Bertie, and the white balls Anna and Bella in your first step; then select the two red balls Charlie and Donnie in your second" OR ""select the red balls called Charlie and Donnie, and the white balls Anna and Bella in your first step; then select the two red balls Alfie and Bertie in your second" OR ""select the red balls called Alfie and Donnie, and the white balls Anna and Bella in your first step; then select the two red balls Charlie and Bertie in your second" etc. However the book's method only counts "Alfie and Bertie and Charlie and Donnie and Anna and Bella" once.

Comment: ( no offence i genuinely wonder ) what kind of training/brain does it take for someone to come up with such complex sentences, are you perhaps a lawyer ( bcz the only other place i have seen unnecessarily complex English is in law books )

i made chat gpt restructure your answer a bit , i still cant understand it [link](https://imgur.com/a/L4ktqMb) `Link`

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, either four red and two white balls are selected, three balls of each color are selected, or two red and four white balls are selected from five red and six white balls.  Hence, the number of selections with at least two balls of each color is
$$\binom{5}{4}\binom{6}{2} + \binom{5}{3}\binom{6}{3} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{4}$$

By designating two of the red balls as the two red balls and two the black balls as the two black balls, you count each selection with four balls of one color six times, once for each of the $\binom{4}{2}$ ways you could have designated two of the four balls of that color as the balls of that color, and each selection with three balls of each color nine times, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{2}$ ways you could have designated two of the three balls of each color as the balls of that color.

To illustrate the case in which you select four red and two white balls, suppose the red balls are $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4, r_5$, the white balls are $w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4, w_5, w_6$, and you select $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4, w_1, w_2$.  Your method counts this case six times.

$$
\begin{array}{c c c}
\text{two red balls} & \text{two white balls} & \text{two additional balls}\\
r_1, r_2 & w_1, w_2 & r_3, r_4\\
r_1, r_3 & w_1, w_2 & r_2, r_4\\
r_1, r_4 & w_1, w_2 & r_2, r_3\\
r_2, r_3 & w_1, w_2 & r_1, r_4\\
r_2, r_4 & w_1, w_2 & r_1, r_3\\
r_3, r_4 & w_1, w_2 & r_1, r_2
\end{array}
$$

By symmetry, you also count each case in which you select two red and four white balls six times.

To illustrate the case in which you select three red and three white balls, suppose you select $r_1, r_2, r_3, w_1, w_2, w_3$.  Your method counts this case nine times.

$$
\begin{array}{c c c}
\text{two red balls} & \text{two white balls} & \text{two additional balls}\\
r_1, r_2 & w_1, w_2 & r_3, w_3\\
r_1, r_2 & w_1, w_3 & r_3, w_2\\
r_1, r_2 & w_2, w_3 & r_3, w_1\\
r_1, r_3 & w_1, w_2 & r_2, w_3\\
r_1, r_3 & w_1, w_3 & r_2, w_2\\
r_1, r_3 & w_2, w_3 & r_2, w_1\\
r_2, r_3 & w_1, w_2 & r_1, w_3\\
r_2, r_3 & w_1, w_3 & r_1, w_2\\
r_2, r_3 & w_2, w_3 & r_1, w_1\\
\end{array}
$$

Notice that
$$\color{red}{\binom{4}{2}}\binom{5}{4}\binom{6}{2} + \color{red}{\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{2}}\binom{5}{3}\binom{6}{3} + \color{red}{\binom{4}{2}}\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{4} = \color{red}{3150}$$

Comment: i still dont get this , permutations and probability is my weak concepts , no matter how many times i study it , i dont get it at all , so can you correct my formula to , make it count to 425 ( i mean , to modify my solution , why is picking 2 balls from each urn wrong? ) , and why cant i pick 2 balls separately after that ? from the remaining balls? )

Comment: Your method is not salvageable.  The problem is that your sets of red balls, white balls, and additional balls are not disjoint, so your method counts each case with four red balls and two white balls six times, each case with four white balls and two red balls six times, and each case with three red balls and three white balls nine times, as my examples illustrate.